# Apache rewrite not working on custom extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a PHP web app which will route every incoming request to the index.php same as WordPress or Joomla.

Following .htaccess is used to implement the feature.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It is working on Wamp server [Windows] and IIS but when I migrate the app to the Ubuntu 16.04.02 [Apache 2.4.18, php7.0.18, Google Cloud Engine], it stops working for some custom extension file. It still working on normal php files thought.

I created a folder called service to put the web service php files and named the files as ****.svc.php and used with ****.svc url. It was working fine before but it is not on the Ubuntu and shown the following error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /service/retrieve_opened_rs.svc was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at ******* Port 80
```

I believe this is the configuration issue but I still cannot figure out how to fix after 3 days. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have the `Multiviews` option enabled. This never behaves well along with rewrite rules, especially with "double" extensions like `.svc.php`

Add this at the top of your `.htaccess` file and that should take care of it:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

You might have to tweak your `AllowOverride` directive (from the main Apache conf) if you don't have the rights to modify `Options` from an `.htaccess` file.